# What is the meaning of ACAI and ATCI in Air Cadets?

Tags: airline-operations

For my staff cadet course, I need to know what ACAI and ACTI stand for but I can't find it anywhere. Would anybody be able to notify me of what this means?

Comment: The only ACAI abbreviation related to aviation I know is for the Afghanistan Civil Aviation Institute, but somehow I doubt that's what you're looking for.
EDIT: After some research I've found another one: Aerostar Continued Airworthiness Instructions. For hot air balloons manufactured by Aerostar.

Comment: I've also noticed that in the question heading it says "ATCI" but in the question body it says "ACTI".

Comment: I can't answer your question, but if you're already in the Air Cadets then you hopefully have a better chance of finding an 'official' answer than the rest of us. So if and when you do, please feel free to answer your own question, that's absolutely OK here.

Answer (score 2):

Those four letters can be abbreviations for many things related to aviation. Taking into account that this is for a staff cadet course, I think the most likely candidates are:

- Air Cadet Administrative
  Instructions
- Air Cadet Training Instructions

[Source](http://www.967atc.co.uk/resources/air-cadet-publications/)

Answer (score 0):

**ACAI** could stand for following:

1. Afghanistan Civil Aviation Institute.
2. Some building in Serbia, which is related to aviation. ([Source](http://www.icao.int/Meetings/GACS/Documents/Speaker%20Presentations/Day%201/Session%202/3-Muzaffar.Ismail.Ministry%20of%20Transportation.Indonesia.pdf))
3. Air Cadet Administrative Instructions. ([Source](http://www.967atc.co.uk/resources/air-cadet-publications/))

**ATCI** stands for Air Traffic Control Instruction.
This acronym appears very rarely. And refers to training of Air Traffic controllers.